# How to extract url from onclick javascript using selenium : Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

from a page having code(as can be seen in inspect element and not in the source code) as:

```
<div id="download_div" class="row" style="margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 2%">
<p id="download_sub_text" class="hide-on-small-only" style="text-align: center;">
    You could also download directly by
    <a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'link', 'click_here', 'wholesale.item');"
        href="http://example.com/f2c9bd13afd7a17af35ad30a2c593c7f4bea2dd347b4149">
        clicking here!
    </a>
```

I want to extract the href link. But the `driver.page_source` do not work as it is a part of a script, so from where do I need to extract exactly if not source code and what exactly can be the **xpath** here?

Also, if possible- This page triggers a file-download(download link being-"http://example.com/f2c9bd13afd7a17af35ad30a2c593c7f4bea2dd347b4149") so if this link can be captured, then that will solve my case.

Comment: Can you provide the actual url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to locate your link element, you use this xpath -

```
//p[@id = 'download_sub_text']/a
```

Then, to get the value of attribute, you use `get_attribute()` method. To get the value of the `href` attribute of your element -

```
required_url = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@id = 'download_sub_text']/a").get_attribute("href")
print(required_url)
```

Also, if you want to get the link to which it redirects to after clicking it, you can take the `current_url` after clicking the button -

```
required_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@id = 'download_sub_text']/a")
required_button.click()
required_url = driver.current_url
```

Comment: Could you propose a solution without clicking?